# Scroll divs in Android

Tags: android, jquery, html, css, scroll

Im building an App in Android and i have a div that have many divs inside, but when the amount of divs overflows the container size the screen does not scroll. I have tryed a lot of things:
- Overflow:auto and chidren with position:relative, doesnt work, not even a little.
- IScroll: It only works when i load it on the index.html and call it there. But the container im using is created later, when i go to another page, so when i call if from there it does not work at all.
- Other many CSS styles and properties and none worked.
Here is the divs hierarchy:

```
<div id="pageContent">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="container" style="height: 100%; overflow:auto">
        // HERE I LOAD THE PAGE
             <div id="search" style="height: 100%">
             </div>
             <div id="mapHeader" class="resultsModeBar">
             </div>
             <div id="pharmacyResultsList" style="padding: 15px;">
                  <div id="pharmacyResultListHeader" class="rounded" style="background-color:#f0f0f1;margin: 0 auto;padding: 10px;margin-bottom: 10px;">
                  </div>
                  <div id="pharmacyResultListBody" class="rounded" style="border: 1px solid;border-color:#EA600A;margin: 0 auto;">
                      // HERE ARE THE DIVS THAT I WANT TO SCROLL
                  </div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this app is built as a webpage, you should be able to open it in an installed browser or using a WebView and have it scroll correctly.

Beyond that, I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're trying to do, but here are my thoughts:

If you want "HERE I LOAD THE PAGE" to stay in place, you can do it one of two ways.  Either wrap the part you want static in a `position: fixed` span

```
<span style="position: fixed">// HERE I LOAD THE PAGE</span>
```

or you can put the text that you want scrollable into a ScrollBox!  ScrollBoxes have defined widths and heights and will basically define a section of the page to be scrollable.

`<div style="height:120px; width:120px; overflow:auto;">
    <div id="pharmacyResultListBody" class="rounded" style="margin: 0 auto;">
        // HERE ARE THE DIVS THAT I WANT TO SCROLL
    </div>
</div>`

[Check it out live here.](https://jsfiddle.net/y45ypqut/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I think yours is a good solution, but i think i have a bigger problem: Im working with an already started project, and when i pasted the scrollbox you sujested it shows exactly as your fiddle but without the scroll bars, im inspecting the html to see if i see a property causing this to happen...i dont know that much of css so if you have any idea of what property could cause a inner div to loose it "scroll" property it would be great!

Comment: I have already fixed it. The problem is that some angelical soul posted a "e.preventDefault()" on page load so it was not handling events as it should. Many thanks for your time!

Comment: I'm very happy that my suggestion helped!